# Stack Overflow crashes on IE9

Tags: support, internet-explorer-9

I can use Stack Overflow for a while on IE9 with no problems. Then all of a sudden continual crashes (see below) - doesn't matter if all add-ons are diasbled and/or if SO is set to Compatability Mode. Drives me nuts - I know I can use Chrome or FF (and I usually do flip over when it starts to happen), but a problem is a problem and avoidance is no cure.

The tab crashes and IE9 resets it and then it promptly crashes again - in compat mode its worse because IE doesn't even try to recover it, it just freezes.

```
Details:

 Description:  
  A problem caused this program to stop interacting with Windows.

 Problem signature:   Problem Event Name:   AppHangB1   Application
 Name:  iexplore.exe   Application Version: 9.0.8112.16421   Application
 Timestamp: 4d76255d   Hang Signature:  b756   Hang Type:   131072   OS
 Version:   6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.1   Locale ID:   2057   Additional Hang
 Signature 1:   b75626d1f812fa589fef16b286fb9c5a   Additional Hang
 Signature 2:   f30f   Additional Hang Signature
 3: f30f96b27c503c633f91b92b39a35b82   Additional Hang Signature
 4: b756   Additional Hang Signature
 5: b75626d1f812fa589fef16b286fb9c5a   Additional Hang Signature
 6: f30f   Additional Hang Signature
 7: f30f96b27c503c633f91b92b39a35b82

 Read our privacy statement online:  
 http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=104288&clcid=0x0409

 If the online privacy statement is not available, please read our
 privacy statement offline:   C:\Windows\system32\en-US\erofflps.txt
```

Comment: Is there a crash dump available somewhere? Do you remember something that could be somewhat affect IE9? Did you get a Windows Update that could affect IE9? I don't think the details are useful as they are, I can't find anything about the main hang signature and the rest look like addresses or values. Please try [this fix it](http://support.microsoft.com/mats/ie_freezes_or_crashes/en-us) and [these reset instructions](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/tips-for-solving-problems-with-internet-explorer). AppHangB1 is way too generic, IE9 131072 gives some results on Google...

Comment: No crash dump is evident (just a tab crash rather than app crash - event log says the same as the above). It's been happening since I upgraded to IE9 and as I said works fine for a while, I do not automatically accept Win Updates, and have not installed anything IE wise since the the upgrade from Win update, so I can to some degree say it's probably not an update. I have installed the Fix you posted, but requires a reboot, so will check back later.

Comment: Hmm, I wonder if a fresh installation instead of an upgrade could help. If the fix(es) don't work, completely removing and re-installing could be an option...

Comment: Nice to get a down vote for reporting a problem - guess I shouldn't in future!

Comment: Thank Tom - I'll try the fix when I reboot later tonight (have a planned reboot anyway). Might try an step back to IE8 and reinstall if I have to, but truthfully will probably just use FF for these sites if the fix you provided doesn't help.

Comment: That's because this is most likely not a bug with Stack Overflow itself, they are most likely not going to remove the piece of code that could result into your issue. Alternatively, there is Super User for these kinds of reports. But let's first see whether we get to a fix before taking any conclusion...

Comment: If you are considering a browser switch, surely consider Google Chrome too. I've been a long time FF user and recently switched and I really felt how FF was way more bloated / slow than Google Chrome...

Comment: Please note that [voting works a bit differently on the Meta site](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences). As Tom suggests, the downvote might be because someone thinks your bug report isn't useful, but it might also be because someone thought this is not a real bug, or isn't worth the developers' time to fix.

Comment: Do you have any plugins installed? Are you running all the latest hotfixes

Comment: @ Waffles - Yes to both, but tried with all add-ons disabled.

Comment: Install the most recent update for Speckie, if you're using it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Millions of people use Stack Overflow every single day, many of them use IE9 so first of all, I'm 100% sure there is no permanent bug in the code of the site causing IE9 to crash or else we would get overflow of reports here.

This means we're talking about local issue in your own machine and/or browser - it's OK to ask for support in such case but it's obviously not a bug in the site.

So:

1. Do you remember what you did before the crash? Meaning, is it happening in the main page, in a question page or when you try to answer?
2. Did it ever happen in IE8 when you had it?

In case the problem won't go away, installing all available Windows updates (even those not directly related to IE9) might solve the issue. [Reference](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/ie9-windows_7/have-an-apphangb1-error-3-4day-internet-explorer-9/2fde05fd-93b6-4976-b344-9ce6490e9ca6).

Comment: Hi, in answer: 1-As far as I can remember its in questions it happens, but adhoc. 2-Didn't happen in IE8. It does happen to some questions over and over and others not at all - I have found no specific reason. Those pages will also work other times. I can have one tab continually crashing on one question and another tab on another q workinh fine. If open the q in the other tab, it too crashes. If it is just me, then fine, I'll live with it (use FF/Chrome), only reason I raised it was in case it was a general/known issue and someone had some little trick that fixes it.

Comment: [run out of chars] Was just going to add, thanks all you guys that tried to help. I guess this thread can be closed as it seem its just my computer and not a general issue. Thanks again.

Comment: Cheers and sorry I couldn't be of more help.